# Selenium Grid c# - Running Multiple Browsers in Node Machine

Tags: c#, selenium, remotewebdriver, selenium-grid2

I'm automating my test cases in c# using selenium Grid, I have hub as my windows machine and my node is MAC. I wanted to run multiple browsers on node machine, say Firefox, Chrome, Safari.

My hub command line is

```
java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.48.2.jar -role hub
```

My node command line is

```
enjava -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.48.2.jar -Dwebdriver.chrome.driver="chromedriver.exe" -role node -hub http://ip:4444/grid/register -port 4507 -browser browserName=chrome maInstances=5, maxSessoin=5 -browser browserName=firefox maxInstances=5, maxSessoin=5 -browser browserName=safari maxInstances=5, maxSessoin=5
```

My C# snippet

```
    public static RemoteWebDriver Instance { get; set; }
    public static void Initialize()
    {
        DesiredCapabilities capabilities = new DesiredCapabilities();
        capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.Firefox();
        capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.Chrome();
        capabilities = DesiredCapabilities.Safari();
        capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.BrowserName, "firefox");
        capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.BrowserName, "chrome");
        capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.BrowserName, "safari");
        capabilities.SetCapability(CapabilityType.Platform, new Platform(PlatformType.Mac));
        Instance = new RemoteWebDriver(new Uri("http://ip:4507/wd/hub"), capabilities);

    }
```

Comment: What exactly is the question ? Can you please clarify ? Oh btw your Initialize() method has a problem. You are merely overwriting the browser name and eventually its getting set to "safari".

Comment: My question is "How to automate multiple browsers at the same time in the node machine? using selenium grid". And what will be the changes I've to do in my code

Comment: Did you run the hub before the node?